# Actualizar toda una columna

Tags: laravel

necesito hacer un Update de toda una columna user_id

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma que utilizo siempre es esta:

```
 $nuevoIngreso = Pedidos::find($id);
 $nuevoIngreso->user_id = 2;
 $nuevoIngreso->save();
```

El problema es que me actualiza un solo registro, yo necesito actualizar todos donde el valor de user_id sea 1.

Comment: Fijate mass updates en la doc https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si quieres cambiar de un ID de usuario a otro puedes usar un where y si no necesitas los datos no hagas un ->get() o ->find(), así ahorras tiempo.

```
Pedidos::where('user_id', 1)->update(['user_id'=> 2]);
```